# Can I inspect inside a parameter in a Mockito when() statement?

Tags: scala, testing, mockito

I am using Mockito with Scala, and I have a when() statement that looks like this:

```
when(iService.find(any[InventoryRequest])).thenReturn(invResponse)
```

This works, but I'd like to make a bunch of these that vary the return response based on the payload inside the InventoryRequest, which is a case class.

So I would do things like:

```
when(iService.find(any[InventoryRequest] and therequest.field==1)).thenReturn(invResponse1)
when(iService.find(any[InventoryRequest] and therequest.field==2)).thenReturn(invResponse2)
```

... and so on. Essentially looking at the parameter passed and, based on it, return a different response.

Yes, I could do this by creating a whole bunch of different test classes, but I'm wondering if Mockito has the capability I'm looking for here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to implement custom logic in your stub, you can use the `thenAnswer` method, which takes a custom `Answer[T]` as parameter. You will have to implement an answer with your custom logic. Here's an exemple, using an anonymous implementation of `Answer`:

```
when(iService.find(any[InventoryRequest])).thenAnswer(
  new Answer[ResponseType] {
    def answer(invocation: InvocationOnMock): ResponseType = {
      val args = invocation.getArguments
      val therequest = args(0).asInstanceOf[InventoryRequest] // Not type-safe!
      if (therequest.field == 1) invResponse1 else invResponse2
    }
  }
)
```

It's not very scala-like, since it could be done in a much simpler way with a closure in pure Scala, but it gets the job done.

However, please note that here is what the [Mockito documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#answer_stubs) says about this feature :

> Yet another controversial feature which was not included in Mockito originally. We recommend using simple stubbing with thenReturn() or thenThrow() only. Those two should be just enough to test/test-drive any clean & simple code.

Using this isn't really part of the Mockito philosophy, and it's usually a sign that what you're trying to do with your mock is overly complex (maybe because the code you're testing is too complex itself). Of course, you can probably find some exceptional cases where it's hard to find a better solution, hence why the feature exists at all.